# render a function for expectational error

Tags: angular

I need to display a modal popup when there is  an error...

here is the code

```
handleError2(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
  
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = "{E1 : "+error.message+"} ";
      console.log("E1:  決裁が完了できませんでした（タイムアウト）");      
      this.payment_error = "CUSTOM ERROR 0x01: "+error.message;
     
    } else {
      // server-side error
      errorMessage = "{E2 : "+error.message+"} ";
      console.log("E2:  決裁が完了できませんでした（タイムアウト）");     
    
      this.payment_error = "CUSTOM ERROR 0x02: "+error.message;
      // this.alertmsg();
      
     
    }    
    // alert(" 決裁が完了できませんでした（タイムアウト）");


  

    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

instead of alert, I need to run the `this.alertmsg()`.

but unable to do so. Can anyone help me to render the function in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is looking at this problem, then make it async arrow function.

e.g.:

```
handleError2=async (error) =>{
//code
```

and remove the return

```
}
```